# Run multiple flutter instances in a single-spa web app

Tags: flutter, dart, micro-frontend, single-spa

I have a need to integrate multiple web apps written in Flutter into a final single web app. I am successful in loading assets, main.dart.js files, and routing the web app using single-spa. The only concern is the error message due to loading multiple main.dart.js files.

This is a route-based micro-frontend use case. I hope I get some pointers to move forward. I don't know how I can isolate these main.dart.js scripts. I renamed them( for the sake of it) and still, they are causing issues.

I also thought about the iframe method. But still not been successful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't follow.  You can start by posting the exact error message being shown by single-spa.